# PayPal integration with separated payment method (CC & PP)

Tags: php, paypal, integration, country

I have to implement a regular PayPal payment on a site for a customer. The scenario is:

- the customer's company is located outside of "payment PRO" countries (UAE)
- the visitor has to be enabled to choose payment method on our site itself (choosing credit card or PayPal, but both processed by PayPal with different payment page)
- only a single item payment occurs with variable amount

As I see for Non-US merchants there are not so many options. Is it possible to fulfill the requirements above with PayPal?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

you can use [cybersource.com](http://cybersource.com)

It is the partner of authorize.net

You can list of supported countries [here](http://apps.cybersource.com/library/documentation/dev_guides/Verification_Svcs_SO_API/html/wwhelp/wwhimpl/js/html/wwhelp.htm#href=app_country_territories.12.5.html)

`UAE` is supported here